# Where can I ask questions about video cards and monitors?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was trying to use a 28 inch LED TV set as a monitor for my computer (for gaming) and it didn't work very well.
My question is if it's ok to use TV sets as monitors for computer. For example this monitor: [SAMSUNG 32" UE32J5100](http://www.samsung.com/fr/consumer/tv-av/tv/full-hd/UE32J5100AWXZF)

Where can I ask questions about such things? http://gaming.stackexchange.com is good?

Answer (score 2):

I think [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be the best site because they cover computer hardware in general. Just make sure to include plenty of information on your hardware, how it's all configured and what in particular didn't work well with it.

Answer (score 2):

Over at [Arqade](http://www.arqade.com/) (your suggestion), there would be mixed reception about this issue. Experience has shown me that some of these questions are closed, and some aren't. Also, the only thing 'gaming-related' about your question is that you use your computer for gaming. This shouldn't really change anything.

However, I believe the best site for your question would be **[SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com/)**.

As their [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) says:

> Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking

Thats what your question is all about. Computer hardware.